# Converting a String to a List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

I have one column of a pandas dataframe whose elements are of the form `'[{"foo": 42, "bar": "conversion"}]'`.  That is, they are all lists of dictionaries (of varying length) but saved in the dataframe as strings.

Is there a way to make this column contain actual lists of dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
json.loads('[{"foo": 42, "bar": "conversion"}]')
# [{u'bar': u'conversion', u'foo': 42}]
```

This will only work if your strings are in json format, but the example is so it's very likely that it will work.

Comment: Well, there we go!  Thank you so much.